# css selector for body from a #document

Tags: html, css

```
<iframe id="someid" etc>
    #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" etc>
            <head>...</head>
            <body>
```

I have this in my page and I was wondering if it was possible to access the body in css to apply a style to it...
I tried this : `#twitter-widget-0 > #document body { width: 75%; }` but of course it didn't work only I don't have any idea what the syntaxe could be or if I am trying to achieve is even possible

Comment: You can't do that. Maybe you can find some ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: please post the code as text, not an image.